# .htaccess rewrite not working properly

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, mysql, .htaccess

Okay, my .htaccess file is as follows:

```
 RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(([A-Za-z0-9\-]+/)*[A-Za-z0-9\-]+)?$ $1.php

RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$0 !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)(\.)(.*)$ profile.php?url=$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/conversation/$0 !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)(\.)(.*)$ conversation.php?with=$1 [L,QSA]
```

The first 2 rewrites work fine, no problems at all.
Its the second one that does not work as planned. I dont see why either, its the same line as the previous one, just altered for a different file.

I get this error on all of my pages with this configuration.

Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/ddd/public_html/ddd/conversation.php:1) in /home/ddd/public_html/ddd/conversation.php on line 24

Comment: check if there is any echo,print or any other output before header("Location: ") in conversation.php file

Comment: also your second and third rule creates confusion as they are identical with different files

Comment: @PravinS so how do i stop the confusion?

Comment: Also @PravinS There is no echo or any other outputs before header("Location");

Comment: try adding some extra character in rule, may be like this
RewriteRule ^a/(.*)/(.*)/ file1.php
RewriteRule ^b/(.*)/(.*)/ file2.php

may this will help you

Comment: What does line 24 of `/home/ddd/public_html/ddd/conversation.php` say? Something must have already been output, otherwise you wouldn't get this error. Also, your question is confusing: "The first 2 rewrites work fine (...) Its the second one that does not work as planned." ??